# SwiftUI Picker Stops Working When Dismiss Keyboard Is Added To ZStack

Tags: swiftui

I am working on a SwiftUI app that's using a UIViewRepresentable for a UIPickerView that allows a TextField to act like a SegmentedPickerView. In order to exit the picker I am using a dismissKeyboard call that I attach to the view. When I add it to the View a SwfitUI Picker that is part of the view stops responding. I am guessing this is because the view as a whole is acting to dismiss the picker. Is there a way to work around this?

**Dismiss Picker Code**

```
#if canImport(UIKit)
extension View {
    func dismissKeyboard() {
        let resign = #selector(UIResponder.resignFirstResponder)
        UIApplication.shared.sendAction(resign, to: nil, from: nil, for: nil)
    }
}
#endif
```

**UIViewRepresentable**

```
struct TextFieldWithPickerAsInputView : UIViewRepresentable {
    
    var data : [String]
    var fieldTitle : String
    var function: (() -> Void)? = nil
    @Binding var selectionIndex : Int
    @Binding var text : String
    
    private let textField = UITextField()
    private let picker = UIPickerView()
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> TextFieldWithPickerAsInputView.Coordinator {
        Coordinator(textfield: self)
    }
    
    func makeUIView(context: UIViewRepresentableContext<TextFieldWithPickerAsInputView>) -> UITextField {
        picker.delegate = context.coordinator
        picker.dataSource = context.coordinator
        picker.backgroundColor = UIColor(Color.pacificBlueAccent)
        picker.tintColor = .black
        textField.placeholder = fieldTitle
        textField.inputView = picker
        textField.font = UIFont(name: Fonts.gse, size: 16.0)
        textField.delegate = context.coordinator
        return textField
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UITextField, context: UIViewRepresentableContext<TextFieldWithPickerAsInputView>) {
        uiView.text = text
    }
    
    class Coordinator: NSObject, UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate , UITextFieldDelegate {
        
        private let parent : TextFieldWithPickerAsInputView
        
        init(textfield : TextFieldWithPickerAsInputView) {
            self.parent = textfield
        }
        
        func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
            return 1
        }
        func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
            return self.parent.data.count
        }
        func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
            return self.parent.data[row]
        }
        func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
            self.parent.$selectionIndex.wrappedValue = row
            self.parent.text = self.parent.data[self.parent.selectionIndex]
            //self.parent.textField.endEditing(true) This dismisses the picker when the picker stops moving. Very annoying.
            
        }
        func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
            if self.parent.function != nil {
                self.parent.function!()
                print("Called")
            }
            self.parent.textField.resignFirstResponder()
        }
    }
}
```

**View Code**

```
return ZStack {
            Color.pacificBlue
                .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
            ScrollView(.vertical, showsIndicators: false) {
                VStack {
                    Picker("", selection: self.$listingType) {
                        ForEach(self.listingTypes, id: \.self) {
                            Text($0.uppercased())
                                .font(.custom((Fonts.gse), size: 16))
                                .fontWeight(.medium)
                        }
                    } // Picker
                    .pickerStyle(SegmentedPickerStyle())
                    .frame(width: screen/1.5)
                    .padding(.top, 5)
                    .padding(.bottom, 5)
                    TextFieldWithPickerAsInputView(...)
                } // VStack
            } // ScrollView
        } // ZStack
        .onTapGesture {
            self.dismissKeyboard()
        }
```

}